# Как организовать запрос на выборку статей sql laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

### Статьи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Регионы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица publication содержит полный адрес Россия, городской округ Краснодар, хутор Ленина адрес получаем из Яндекс карт поле называется place. Список регионов и город относящихся к региону Краснодарский край, г. Краснодар.
теперь необходимо по имени региона выбирать посты .
Но если использовать обычный like  %Краснодарский край, г Краснодар%.
выборка не происходит.
Как можно всю строку региона и города сопоставить с адресом поста ,если есть хоть одно вхождение строки региона в адрес поста?

```
public function ajaxPagination(Request $request)

    {
        $regName='';
        if(empty($request->region)==false){
            Cookie::forever('region',$request->region);
            $regName=$request->region;
        }
        else{
            $regName=$name = Cookie::get('region', 'Краснодарский край Краснодар');
        }

  $posts = Publication::where('place','LIKE', "%$regName%")->latest()->paginate(6);



        if ($request->ajax()) {

            return view('paginate/ajaxPagPost', compact('posts'));

        }



        return view('paginate/ajaxPagPost',compact('data'));

    }
```

Comment: Можно вынести эти данные в отдельные столбцы, чтобы в дальнейшем иметь возможность легко подставить это в поиск и создать фильтр. Это как один из вариантов решения проблемы, но не единственный.

Comment: ну проблема в том что пользователю несколько раз предвидеться кликать по select выбирая либо город либо район

Comment: Давайте вы добавите схему таблицы и конечный результат который вы хотите получить, а мы посмотрим на доступные варианты решения

Comment: Недостаточно информации для ответа или нечётко сформулирован вопрос. Покажите формат данных, в котором они у вас хранятся, покажите конкретный запрос, покажите релевантный участок кода из Laravel.

Comment: Разбирайте адрес региона на токены (видимо, по запятой), отбрасывайте незначащие (если они есть - скажем, все, кроме первых двух), ищите значащие. Но лучше сразу индексировать статью по адресу, в момент создания (искать наиболее подходящий `id`, или список `id`-ов), и потом использовать готовый формализованный в числовое значение адрес.

Answer (score 0):

Правильное решение это сделать связь по ID постов и регионов. Но если такой возможности нет, тогда можно сделать иначе, но если будут встречаться одинаковые названия городов в разных регионах, выборка будет неверной.

В таблице регионов лучше иметь отдельно название города -  Краснодар . У Вас получиться следующая структура:

**name**  =    Краснодарский край, г. Краснодар                          |
**nameCity** =   Краснодар

И уже делать Like выборку постов по nameCity

**$posts = Publication::where('place','LIKE', "%Краснодар%")**

Или если если возможность с яндекс карт получать город отдельно, то делать выборку по столбцу city уже через равенство.

**$posts = Publication::where('city', "Краснодар")**